# VirtualDub & FFDShow - couldn't load up XviD AVI

Tags: video, 64-bit, codec

I installed VirtualDub recently (32bit) on 64bit Windows 10 machine. I decided to use 32bit version in term of using DeLogo filter, which is 32bit. I have already installed VLC Media Player in order to be able to play various video formats and I've already installed FFDShow codecs with VFW built-in tech. Settings for XviD and DivX are to use libavcodec and these codecs are also 32bit installation (well, should be, they're installed in `Program Files (x86)` folder). But VirtualDub can't seem to find these codecs and when I try to import a video, it says it couldn't locate XviD decoder. Everything important is installed, what could I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Libav contains an Mpeg-4 codec, but not the Xvid or Divx codec specifically. I'd suggest installing the actual Xvid codec for encoding/decoding the Divx/Xvid format. Once installed, vdub should find it just fine.  https://www.xvid.com

Comment: Thank you, solved :) I did not know that libavcodec does not support XviD :D